# How to get current riak-repl clustername via HTTP

Tags: riak

I know that Riak has HTTP support for a lot of information ie:

```
http://<Node IP>:<port>/stats
```

And that I can get the current clustername via the command line:

```
riak-repl clustername
```

What I can't find in the Riak docs is how to retrieve the Cluster name via HTTP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

making a call to http://servername:8098/riak-repl/stats exposes "cluster_name"